# pyexcel reading floats correctly

Tags: python, pyexcel

I am trying to read meta information from ".xlsx' file.
`Pandas` is reading the float numbers correctly, however `pyexcel` is reading numbers truncated.

Example:

`Pandas`

> [-6.6158600000000001e-20, 1.91469e-15, -2.2699600000000002e-11,
>   1.06038e-07, 4.5583400000000001e-05, 1.6020000000000001]

`pyexcel`

> [ -6.61586000e-20,   1.91469000e-15,  -2.26996000e-11, 1.06038000e-07,
>   4.55834000e-05,   1.60200000e+00]

Is there any way to get `pyexcel` to format floating point numbers.

Comment: Might it be that either the numbers are stored with different accuracy (single vs double float), or they are simply printed with a different number of digits?

Comment: Not sure whether I have understood the first part of your comment - I have saved above-mentioned data with scientific notation (with 10 decimal).    

The answer to the second part of the comment - the decimal values are being truncated. So I am assuming it's problem with number conversion in `pyexcel`.

Comment: pandas uses xlrd for reading xlsx whereas pyexcel could use pyexcel-xls(xlrd) or pyexcel-xlsx(openpyxl) to read it. which plugin did you use?

Comment: I am using `pyexcel` with `pyexcel-xlsx` installed as plugin.

Comment: Could you please install pyexcel-xls(and pip uninstall pyexcel-xlsx) to see if the output are the same as pandas? pyexcel-xls uses xlrd so in theory the output should be the same.